# How to upload a file into S3 bucket using CloudFormation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

How do I upload a file into my AWS S3 bucket CloudFormation template?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: s3bucketuser
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't upload files through CloudFormation, that's not supported because CFN doesn't have access to your local filesystem.

What I usually do:

- Call `cloudformation` task from *Ansible*
- CFN creates the bucket and in the `Outputs` exports the bucket name
- Ansible uploads the files using `s3_sync` in the next task once the CFN one is done.

Comment: See other answer, it's perfectly doable. Also one can define a Lambda function inside the template which can be executed and do whatever you want. Using custom resources anyhow. Also see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-s3-custom-resources/

Comment: I use custom lambda resource too for anything outside of CF capabilities. No dependency on any 3rd party this way.

Answer (score 26):

AWS provides a sample [Macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) that may help, depending on your use case: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/a11722d/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/S3Objects.

1. Create a separate CloudFormation stack with [macro.template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/ef40221/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/S3Objects/macro.template). This creates the Transform Macro "S3Objects" that will then be available to any other stack in the region. The [README.md](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) explains how to "package" the macro template prior to adding to CloudFormation (it will need to include a separate source file for a Lambda function).
2. The file [example.template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/ef40221/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/S3Objects/example.template) provides sample usage. Note the top-level [Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html) section that refers to `S3Objects`, which allows the use of `Type: AWS::S3::Object`.

In the provided [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/ef40221/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/S3Objects/example.template), the `Body` property allows for entering text directly in the YAML or JSON template. To expand on that, one can use [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to create a file with parameters or properties from other resources:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Transform: S3Objects

Parameters:
  ANameField:
    Type: String

Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: s3bucketuser
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled

  S3Object:
    Type: AWS::S3::Object
    Properties:
      Target:
        Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
        Key: README.md
        ContentType: text/markdown
      Body: !Sub |
        # My text file

        This is my text file for ${ANameField}.
        The region is ${AWS::Region} and my account ID is ${AWS::AccountId}.
        This file is in the ${S3Bucket} bucket. The bucket ARN is ${S3Bucket.Arn},
        and its website endpoint is ${S3Bucket.WebsiteURL}
```

Comment: Weird that this is not a native type. Config files are very easily populated with the template's data.